# Appium - Interact with custom widgets

Tags: android, appium

I’m trying to interact through appium with a custom made widget, that is built as a LinerLayout that wraps an EditText. The LinearLayout adds the EditText progromaticlly. Appium inspector shows the LinearLayout as an editText and for that i am not able to interact with the editText inside the LinearLayout.

In the photo you can see the custom widget selected, and that appium recognizes it as an EditText.

Any Idea how to interact with custom made widgets?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1I6dy.png)

Comment: what action do you want to perform?
and the hierarchy displays the EditText within a LinearLayout only.

Comment: Want to tap/send_keys, any action i try to do doesn't respond. The first EditText (the one that is selected) is actually a LinearLayout - but shown as an EditText in the UIaoutomator

Comment: could you please share an appium inspector screenshot of that? &&
does this LinearLayout(you say)/EditText(i believe) has any id? (i hope the screenshot would capture these details.

Comment: Added an image in the answer before, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKBcX.png) to see uiautomator view

You can see that the last two widgets are inspected as EditText, the one before the last is actually a LinearLayout

Answer (score 0):

You could try to find all the child elements of the linear layout or edittext you think are found correctly like this:

```
@FindAll(@FindBy(xpath = ".../android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/*"))
List<MobileElement> editTexts;
```

With this you get a list of all the elements that Appium **does** find and you can now interact with it.
Hope that helps a bit.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the problem is not that the element is not found. Rather that appium finds it as an EditText and not as a LinearLayout that it really is

Comment: Well for that the source from android would really help. I doubt there is a mismatch in display of layouts and objects via Appium in this case.

Comment: What i eventually did was simply replace the widget with a different one, the original one wasn't working for some reason..

Answer (score 0):

To interact with the element on screen as displayed in the inspector view.

SendKeys using :

```
driver.findElement(By.id("FloatLabeledEditTextEdtText")).sendKeys("abc");
```

Tap/Click using :

```
driver.findElement(By.id("FloatLabeledEditTextEdtText")).click();
```

The id of the element is specified in the inspector, in case you have multiple elements with same id, you can use :

```
List <WebElements> multipleElements = driver.findElement(By.id("FloatLabeledEditTextEdtText"));
multipleElements.get(index).click()/.sendkeys("xyz"); //either action at a time where index is the position of element you want to access
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the problem is not that the element is not found. Rather that appium finds it as an EditText and not as a LinearLayout that it really is